# Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use

Tags: 20.04, xrdp

Need help to resolve this issue.

OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Error : Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use.

journelctl -xe

```
    -- A start job for unit xrdp.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 1785.
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp-sesman[3636]: (3636)(140566295258688)[INFO ] listening to port 3350 on 127.0.0.1
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp[3650]: (3650)(140065546684224)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 3
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp[3650]: (3650)(140065546684224)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp[3650]: (3650)(140065546684224)[ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp[3650]: (3650)(140065546684224)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_VSOCK cid -1 port -1)
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 xrdp[3650]: (3650)(140065546684224)[ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use.
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit xrdp.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit xrdp.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
okt 23 12:01:29 Ubutu20 systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit xrdp.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/suppor
```

netstat -epl

```
sudo netstat -epl | grep 3389
sandesh@Ubutu20:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file

> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

Modify the parameters as follows :

```
port = tcp: //: 3389

use_vsock = false
```

Then restart the xrdp service: `sudo systemctl restart xrdp`

[Explanation of problem](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1403):

> **metalefty**:
>
> use_vsock=yes is no longer prefered but the MS tool still using this
> switch. Report it to the author of the tool and ask them fix it.
>
> P.S. the vsock feature is developed by MS guys. We xrdp team merged
> that but if MS guys do not maintain vsock, it might be removed in
> future. We welcome continuous contributions from MS guys!

Comment: This appears to fix the initial problem since systemctl is now able to bring xrdp up. However, I do not see any windows manager or X session on tty1.

Comment: TL;DR Changing the port from 3389 to any other port like 3390 will fix the issue

Comment: This did work for, the daemon does start now however the xrdp connection does not kick when starting the vm - enhanced session mode support is still greyed out.